# ^M characters in exported file, converting to newlines

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, newline

I exported a CSV from excel to parse using python. When I opened the vimmed the CSV, I noticed that it was all one line with ^M characters where newlines should be.

```
Name, Value, Value2, OtherStuff ^M Name, Value, Value2, OtherStuff ^M
```

I have the file parsed such that I modify the values and put the into a string (using 'rU' mode in csvreader). However, the string has no newlines. So I am wondering, is there a way to split the string on this ^M character, or a way to replace it with a \n?

Comment: That's actually a `\r`.

Answer (score 3):

`^M` is how vim displays windows end-of-line's

The `dos2unix` command should fix those up for you:

```
dos2unix my_file.csv
```

It's due to the different EOL formats on Windows/Unix.

On windows, it's `\r\n`

On Unix/Linux/Mac, it's just `\n`

The `^M` is actually vim showing you the windows CR (Carriage Return) or `\r`

The python `open` command documentation has more information on handling Universal Newlines: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unix system, there is a program called `dos2unix` (and its counterpart `unix2dos`) that will do exactly that conversion.

But, it is pretty much the same as something like this:

```
sed -i -e 's/$/\r/' file
```